# What's the correct format for -AccountExpirationDate for new-aduser?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to bulk-create users from a .csv file and can't figure out how to set an account expiration date using the -accountexpirationdate parameter. Powershell wants me to use System.DateTime. Is that something like 03/01/2023 00:00:00?

Comment: You need to cast the string time to DateTime : ([System.DataTime]"03/01/2023 00:00:00")

Comment: So if I have a column in the csv called AccountExpiredDate with 03/01/2023 00:00:00 for every user and in my powershell script I have a variable $AccountExpiredDate = $user.AccountExpiredDate, how would the New-ADUser -AccountExpiredDate look like?

Comment: A DateTime is a number (number) and can be displayed in many formats.  There is only one way of storing the number in Windows.  You can get today using [System.DateTime]::today.  The number is the number of ticks (100ns) from 1/1/01 and is a long.